# ModRewrite not working for codeigniter site

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I tried a modrewrite for my codeigniter site, but when I went into the htaccess file there was already one.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php?|combine\.php?|_images|assets|_styles|_js|favicon\.ico?|dashboard|mail)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

However, when I try to locally test my site in xxamp, I have to put `index.php` which breaks all my style links. Is there something I'm missing?  When the site is live it isn't required.

EDIT: This site was developed on MAMP on osx, i'm using xampp on windows, think that could be part of the problem?

Comment: Is this a property for codeigniter or php in general?

Comment: mod_rewrite is an Apache module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my CI project I have this data in .htaccess

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /
>
> #Removes access to the system folder by users.
> #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
> #previously this would not have been possible.
> #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
>
> #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
> #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
> #Submitted by: Fabdrol
> #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
>
> #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
> #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
> #request to index.php
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
> ```

Comment: This did it! Thank you! Thats great use of the commenting because I would have never guessed what all that did.

Answer (score 0):

Is apache looking for the .htaccess file? You might want to check your configuration.

Comment: httpdc.conf says a few things:   
`AllowOverride All`   
and 
`<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>`