# From a MAMP dev env to XAMPP

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp, mamp

I'm taking over a codeigniter project that was originally developed in MAMP on OSX.

My php dev environment is a XAMPP on Windows.  Works great for all my other work and projects.  However I copied this app I took over to my htdocs folder and it works but it causes lots of problems with rewriting URLS (for example ModRewrite isn't working when it is suppose to, see [ModRewrite not working for codeigniter site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696469/modrewrite-not-working-for-codeigniter-site)).

Could these problems stem from the two dev environments?  It works fine when on my host, but I need to make changes.

EDIT: Got it back on a MAMP environment, same exact problem.  Looking into config now.

Comment: Do you use the same configuration in both environments (except paths)?

Comment: I really don't think so :(  I know the paths are different though

Comment: @drpcken: Then try that first. Try to use the same configuration (well, except the mentioned paths).

Comment: Do i just get the httpd.conf file?  What other configuration files will I need?

Comment: btw: I think xampp times are over, have a look at Zend Server CE.

Comment: You should focuss more on the fact that you are moving from an OSX environment to a Windows environment, I think this is what is causing most of your problems, rather than the differences between XAMPP and MAMP.

Comment: The reason I like xampp is because I have it setup as a portable environment with dropbox.  Would this be possible with Zend Server?

Comment: @Naatan  I'm only putting it in xampp for development.  I do have a mac but prefer my windows pc for dev.  I'll put it on my mac with mamp and see if it runs right away without problems.  Thanks you

Comment: @naatan @drpcken I don't think this would be the issue because most dev environments (*AMP) are ran as virtual servers anyway.

Comment: @jondavidjohn I can tell from experience that mod_rewrite quite definitely does show some different characteristics based on OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, CodeIgniter specifc environment config issues...

```
system/application/config/config.php
system/application/config/database.php
./index.php
```

Things to check are 'base_url' in config.php

Also on this note, make sure in the code the previous author consistently used `<?= base_url() ?>` for loading assets(css,img,etc..) and other path dependant things.

example url to include a css file `<= base_url() ?>css/cssfile.css` would create the url `http://your.local.host/css/cssfile.css`

and `<?= site_url('controller/function') ?>` would create `http://your.local.host/index.php/controller/function`

make sure for anchor tags they used `<?= site_url('uri/path') ?>` for the href.

Comment: Here is the base_url :  `$config['base_url'] = 'http' . ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 's' : '').'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].str_replace('//','/',dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'/');`

Comment: ok, I would scrap that and replace it with whatever virtualhost you have set up for local dev, ex.  `$config['base_url'] = 'http://dev.local';`  where dev.local is whatever you have setup as the siteroot.

Comment: That was it thank you!  My initial page works but links don't because it is requiring me to put `base_url/index.php/products`

Comment: Ok, make sure you review the documentation and more specifically for links, make sure you re-read my original answer, specifcally about `base_url()` AND `site_url()`

Comment: well for the links they used base_url, which is weird because it seems to generate the index.php when rendered.  Here's an example of an <a> tag: `<a href="<?=base_url()?>products/id/12">Link</a>`.  This produced the url  http://localhost/Site/products/id/12.  This link doesn't work until I type `index.php` after the Site/ segment.  This is what I'm trying to remove

Comment: ok, so instead of the example href you gave, use this `<?= site_url('products/id/12') ?>`

Answer (score 1):

1 Check how sitepath is, eg. it was locahost/~user/ci and is localhost/ci

2 if is different Change both config.php and .htaccess

3 make sure that htaccess works. CHeck if module is there and check if allow .htaccess on httpd.conf

See what is different from Mamp to Xampp.